# How to change div background color, when hovering on button which is present in the same div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying changing div color when button is hover. code is working if the button is present outside div, but i need button in the same div?

Code :

```css
.card {
  height: 20em;
  width: 10em;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.btn+.card {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 card">
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Hover me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Try it following codes.

```css
.card {
  height: 20em;
  width: 10em;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.card>div {
  height: 100%;
}

.btn:hover+div {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 card">
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Hover me</button>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no parent selector. https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/

You can accomplish this with jQuery (a javascript library).

```js
$('.btn').hover(function() {
  $(this).closest('.card').addClass('hover');
}, function() {
  $(this).closest('.card').removeClass('hover');
});
```

```css
.hover {
  background: black;
}

.card {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 card">
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Hover me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can choose a combinator i.e. `.card .btn` and write the hover logic.
eg.

```
.card .btn:hover,
.card .btn:active {
    background-color: "color name";
}
```

Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/Lrvsr0uf/

Comment: op is trying to change the div background when hovering over the child button.